# Lotus Notes 7 Crashes at Splashscreen on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, lotus-notes

My Lotus Notes 7 client is crashing while the splash screen is up. It is very frustrating because there is no error message displayed, nothing I can see in the Event Viewer, I've looked through several console.log files and nothing is there either. I just have no idea why this is happening.

**UPDATES**

Yes, this is on a a business network and owned by the company I work for. No one wants to help me here because they are still waiting for Win 7.

Lotus Notes 7 is not officially supported in Windows 7 but I had it working on this machine until I started updating Windows. Could installing the Java JDK be the cause?

Compatibility mode only made it do the same thing in slow motion.

**Update2**

The debug log doesn't update every time I run it. I'm not sure what exactly causes it to update. This is what the latest version made contains...sorry it doesn't seem to be much but, IDK, maybe that is the problem...

```
Host Name       : 2000097W7
User Name       : TheDude
Date            : Mon Jan 12 09:04:43 2015
Windows Dir     : C:\Windows
Arguments       : "C:\Users\AdminDude\Desktop\Backup\Copy\Portable\lotus\notes\nsd.exe"
NSD Version     : 7.0.1.2209 (Release 7.0.1)
OS Version      : Windows Vista 6.1 (Build 7601), PlatID=2, Service Pack 1 (4 Processors)
Build time      : Wed Jan 18 06:26:31 2006
Latest file mod : Thu Nov 10 15:50:18 2005
ERROR (0): No notes processes seem to be running

<@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@>
Section: Notes Process Summary (Time 09:04:44)
<@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@>

<@@ Notes Process Summary -> Instance #1 (current) (Time 09:04:44) @@>

                Ini File   : C:\Users\AdminDude\Desktop\Backup\Copy\Portable\lotus\notes\notes.ini
                Data Dir   : H:\lotus\notes\data
ERROR (0): nothing to report: no active processes found for this instance


Started at: Mon Jan 12 09:04:43 2015
Ended   at: Mon Jan 12 09:04:44 2015


Generated Messages:

   WARNING (0): NSD is unable to obtain privileges for some debugging operations.  If you are running as a limited or restricted user then NSD will be unable to obtain some of the information it is attempting to collect.  NSD will also produce error messages when privileged operations fail.  However, useful data such as Notes/Domino callstacks will still be collected.
   ERROR (0): AdjustTokenPrivileges failed - (1300) Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [  System:    4] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [    smss:  256] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [   csrss:  352] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ wininit:  596] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [services:  652] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [   lsass:  668] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [     lsm:  676] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ svchost:  820] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ svchost:  900] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ svchost:  996] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ svchost:  360] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ svchost:  384] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ svchost:  412] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ svchost:  884] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ spoolsv: 1088] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ svchost: 1128] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [  armsvc: 1220] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ svchost: 1256] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [HeciServer: 1292] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [MsDepSvc: 1360] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [sqlservr: 1428] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [   SASrv: 1484] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [sqlwriter: 1576] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ svchost: 1616] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ICCProxy: 2748] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [SearchIndexer: 2268] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ svchost: 3392] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [DeliveryService: 1948] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [Jhi_service: 1476] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [     LMS: 3436] - (5) Access is denied.



Please send the following files:

                NSD Log : H:\LOTUS\NOTES\DATA\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT\nsd_W32I_2000097W7_2015_01_12@09_04_43.log
```

Comment: Is this a business computer and business software? Is it owned by a company you work for?

Comment: What versions of Windows does `Lotus Notes 7` support exactly?  It likely only supports Windows XP so try using compatibility mode.

Comment: Did it ever work for you on that computer, or is this a new thing? If it has worked, and this problem is new, have you tried simply reinstalling Notes?

Comment: Install the version of Java this version requires any other version won't be supported but sounds like you should update the program also to one that supports Windows 7

Comment: Notes 7 is not written in Java. (Notes 8 and above are a different, and more complicated to explain, story.) Notes 7 can run Java code as part of Notes applications, but it provides its own JVM for that. Neither those apps, nor the Notes client itself would be affected at all by the JDK that you have installed.

Comment: What does the nsd- file (IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT- directory) say about the cause for the crash?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of basic troubleshooting that is usually done when supporting Notes. Usually you'd start with your company's help desk who would do all of that and eventually uninstall (and also manually delete left behind stuff) and then reinstall Notes.

If you haven't already done so, I'd try deleting any of the .nsf files that get automatically regenerated, like cache.ndk and bookmark.nsf back when I supported notes 7, rebooting and then deleting cache.ndk and bookmark.nsf fixed a bunch of broken installations.

You can backup the workspace and then delete it and notes will create a new blank one.

You may also try backing up your names.nsf and then creating a new one by copying pernames.ntf and renaming the copy to names.nsf.

If you know all your settings, you can 'refresh' the notes.ini by deleting all of the lines after the directory= line and then leave an extra blank line at the end.

Comment: Notes 7 has no workspace directory....

Comment: Unfortunately, I am the help desk here. I've deleted many different combinations of these files and, so far, it isn't making any difference. One thing I should probably point out is that we have all of our data files on shares. I AM able to use these exact same data files on other machines just fine. I've also manually recreated most of the ini file just to be sure it is correct to no avail.

Comment: It doesn't have a workspace directory, it has a desktop6 or desktop5 desktop file that it uses to maintain the workspace.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling altogether yet?

Comment: @Zach Yes, I even tried going back a version. We don't have anything newer than 7 though.

Comment: did it ever work? With windows 7 and notes 7, there are some files you have to add permissions to if you aren't running as an admin on the pc. you might also do a custom install and specify everything to be under your profile or another directory that you have full permission on.  If it did work at some point and doesn't now, you may have to reinstall windows as well.